# HTML Renders the First SVG in Multiple Elements Instead of the Second

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm having an issue with rendering multiple SVG elements in an HTML file. When I include two different SVG code snippets in an HTML file, it displays the first SVG on each of the SVG elements after rendering. However, if I delete the first one, the second SVG renders perfectly.

Comment: [Codepen link](https://codepen.io/Md-Shafiul-Alam-the-bold/pen/OJdMLWg)

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead. Stackoverflow does support [inline live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both SVG links to pattern with ID `pattern0`. For second SVG change pattern ID and update link to it to solve it.